# COUNT Clicks/Opens for Engagement Scoring

Tags: sql, count, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am a bit rusty on SQL so any assistance is appreciated. I am also referencing my SQL textbook but I thought I would try this out.

I am developing a lead scoring model starting with engagement scoring. I created a data extension  to house the results and used the following query to populate:

```sql
SELECT a.[opportunityid], 
       a.[first name], 
       a.[last name], 
       a.[anticipatedentryterm], 
       a.[funnelstage], 
       a.[programofinterest], 
       a.[opportunitystage], 
       a.[opportunitystatus], 
       a.[createdon], 
       a.[ownerfirstname], 
       a.[ownerlastname], 
       a.[f or j visa student], 
       a.[donotbulkemail], 
       a.[statecode], 
       Count(DISTINCT c.[subscriberkey]) AS 'Clicks', 
       Count(DISTINCT b.[subscriberkey]) AS 'Opens', 
       Count(DISTINCT b.[subscriberkey]) * 1.5 + 
       Count(DISTINCT c.[subscriberkey]) * 3 AS 'Probability' 
FROM   [ug_all_time_joined] a 
       INNER JOIN [open] b 
               ON a.[opportunityid] = b.[subscriberkey] 
       INNER JOIN [click] c 
               ON a.[opportunityid] = c.[subscriberkey] 
GROUP  BY a.[opportunityid], 
          a.[first name], 
          a.[last name], 
          a.[anticipatedentryterm], 
          a.[funnelstage], 
          a.[programofinterest], 
          a.[opportunitystage], 
          a.[opportunitystatus], 
          a.[createdon], 
          a.[ownerfirstname], 
          a.[ownerlastname], 
          a.[f or j visa student], 
          a.[donotbulkemail], 
          a.[statecode]
```

Something is wrong with my COUNT functions, the query populates the same value in both Clicks and Opens and I don't think it's accurate. The result I am aiming for is how many times a subscriber id appears (which would correspond with the individual clicks/opens, each row is a 1 action).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is that surprising?

You have two joins that if you take to their logical conclusion imply that

```
b.[SubscriberKey] = c.[SubscriberKey]
```

Hence, counting distinct values will be the same.

You have not provide sample data or desired results.  I can speculate, though, that you intend `LEFT JOIN`s so you get some values in one table that are not matched in the other.

Answer (score 0):

When you do an inner join, between a and b, your data is filtered when you join a and c, which will give you incorrect results. having no view of your data and no background of your tables, this is the best guess i have